# Получение контекста HDC всех подключенных экранов по отдельности WinApi

Tags: winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, я окончательно запутался: мне необходимо получить контекст - тот которой тип HDC каждого экрана по отдельности.

На [MSDNе](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/hmonitor-and-the-device-context)
написано:

> Любая функция, которая возвращает контекст устройства отображения (DC), обычно возвращает DC для основного монитора. Чтобы получить DC для другого монитора, используйте функцию EnumDisplayMonitors

Но функция  EnumDisplayMonitors - не возвращает и не перечисляет контексты дисплеев(ну или я не понял как их достать), более того, первым параметром функции я должен указать HDC контекст дисплея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, параметр `hdc` в функции `EnumDisplayMonitors` ограничивает перечисление. Значит, нужно указать такой HDC, который покрывает сразу все мониторы. И такой HDC есть, как сказано в [описании функции CreateDC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw):

> If there are multiple monitors on the system, calling
>   `CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL)` will create a DC covering all
>   the monitors.

Соответственно, приходим к такому решению:

```
HDC common_dc = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EnumDisplayMonitors(common_dc, NULL, (MONITORENUMPROC)MonitorEnumProc, NULL);
```

И в callback-функции получаем HDC для каждого монитора:

```
BOOL MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR monitor, HDC hdc, LPRECT rect, LPARAM data) {
    dc_list.push_back(hdc);
    return TRUE;
}
```

---

Можно также отправить в `EnumDisplayMonitors` NULL. Callback-функция в таком случае тоже будет получать NULL вместо HDC, но HMONITOR будет доступен. Так что можно будет получить имя устройства и использовать это имя, чтобы создать DC:

```
BOOL MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR monitor, HDC hdc, LPRECT rect, LPARAM data) {
    MONITORINFOEX info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
    dc_list.push_back(CreateDC(NULL, info.szDevice, NULL, NULL));
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: t3f, Спасибо!  Подскажите почему  dc_list.push_back(CreateDC(NULL, info.szDevice, NULL, NULL)); - info.szDevice ставится во второй параметр, а не в первый ?

Comment: И если возможно, подскажите еще пожалуйста< немного не понимаю, почему этот код работает:`код`HDC common_dc = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EnumDisplayMonitors(common_dc, NULL, (MONITORENUMPROC)MonitorEnumProc, NULL);`код`, а этот нет: `код` EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, (MONITORENUMPROC)MonitorEnumProc, NULL);`код`

Comment: @Optimus1, о первом параметре CreateDC: `The first parameter, pszDriver, is not really a graphics device driver name for Win32 programs. It is a leftover from the Win16 API. The only acceptable value for it is "DISPLAY" for creating a display device context, NULL or "WINSPOOL" for a printer device context.` (из книги "Windows Graphics Programming: Win32 GDI and DirectDraw")

Comment: А насчёт второго вопроса, я уже упоминал в ответе, что если отправить в `EnumDisplayMonitors` NULL вместо HDC, то в callback тоже будет приходить NULL.

Comment: t3f, кстати вот так не получится: <HDC common_dc = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EnumDisplayMonitors(common_dc, NULL, (MONITORENUMPROC)MonitorEnumProc, NULL);
И в callback-функции получаем HDC для каждого монитора:>  Так как HDC в колбек функции возвращается всего вирутального экрана, а не отдльеных моинторов состовляющий этот вирутальный экран. То есть на самом деле, если у меня два монитора:то колбек функция вызовется два раза,но этот HDC -это не HDC отдельного монитора,потомучто <GetDeviceCaps(hdc, BITSPIXEL) << endl;>-при 1ом и 2ом вызове выдает одно значение,а это не так.

Comment: А если что-нибудь нарисовать используя этот HDC, на каком мониторе появляется нарисованное?

Comment: t3f, рисовать пока что к сожалению не умею. Но сделал по другому, сделал скриншот каждого отдельного полученного HDC и сохранил в bmp - все работает, сохраняет какждый рабочий стол каждого монитора по отдельности. Значит дело в функции GetDeviceCaps(hdc, BITSPIXEL), видимо она немного по другому работает. Может быть Вы можете подсказать есть ли какая нибудь другая функция, которая по HDC могла бы возвратить настройку битности этого HDC ?

Comment: @Optimus1 , не думаю что параметры HDC вообще связаны с монитором. Я не уверен точно, но мне кажется что они зависят не от монитора, а от адаптера (видеокарты).

Comment: t3f,Вообщем все работает. Это я был не внимателен.
А не работало, потому что, когда я запускал этот код, у меня на буке как то само сбросилось 16 бит на 32, когда я второй монитор подключал. И в итоге оказывало оба монитора 32 - правильно, но я ожидал увидеть 16 и 32.